# gyp — how to set FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATH?

Tags: ios, xcode, gyp

How do I set `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATH` with `gyp`?

If I do

```
"libraries": [ "foo.framework", ],
```

that field is left blank and Xcode can't find header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking tests I found proper way:

```
"xcode_settings": {
    'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS': [
        '/foo/',
    ],
},
```